# Only show what logged in user has created.Symfony2.8

Tags: php, symfony, entity, relationship, fosuserbundle

I have two table in different bundle Post entity is link to the table User entity. The problem is every users that are logged can see all the products, would like to allow (show) only what logged in user has created.

In my PostRepository.php i added this code but it doesn't works:

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PostRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->select('i')
            ->from('FLYBookingsBundle:Post', 'i')
            ->where('i.roles LIKE :roles')
            ->setParameter('roles', '%owner object%');

        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $owner;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }


/**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    /*
     * @param User $owner
     */
    public function setOwner(User $owner)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

PostController.php

```
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Post();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();
            $entity->setOwner($user);
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only allow show what logged in user has created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34695051/only-allow-show-what-logged-in-user-has-created)

Comment: Using annotation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/security.html#using-expressions-for-complex-security-restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show only posts belonging to logged in user:

1. Each post must be associated with a user.  Create a ManyToOne relationship between the Post entity and the User entity.  See this [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations) since your code is too sparse to guess how best to present a solution.
2. Your show action needs to be restricted to logged in users. Refer to this [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/securing_services.html).
3. Once your show action is restricted, get the user in it: `$user = $this->getUser();`
4. With $user, `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findBy(array('user' => $user ));`

Comment: i really appreciate your help :)  i'm done from the step 1 to 3. the only problem is with the step 4. i inserted this line `$user = $this->getUser();$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findBy(array('user' => $user ));`  in my indexAction but when i refresh my page i got this error: **Unrecognized field: user** i do understand the error it mean that there is not user in my table so i replaced it by owner, because owner entity give the user id in the table post.i don't have an error with owner, but unfortunately it returned all product of every user

Comment: this is my indexAction so you can see what did i do wrong. `public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findBy(array('owner' => $user ));
        $findEntities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findAll();
        $entities  = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($findEntities,$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),9
        );
        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }`

Comment: I made it work like this in my indexAction :  `$user = $this->getUser();
        $findEntities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findBy(array('owner' => $user ));` Thank you :)

Comment: Congratulations.  Glad I could help.